# чем отличается Request Payload от FormData в js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Чем отличается код ajax запроса на сайт FormData от Request Payload?

больше интересует второй вариант.

Comment: Request Payload

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23118249/4928642

Answer (score 6):

Request Payload - это любые данные, отправленные в теле запроса.

А FormData - это определённый формат (`content-type`) передачи данных, а именно [`multipart/form-data`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data). Также возможны форматы `application/json`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` и другие.

Comment: а можете, пожалуйста, показать пример Request Payload запроса.

Comment: @green, нет. Вот у тебя есть яблоко, груша и манго. Чем яблоко отличается от фрукта? Можешь показать пример фрукта?

Comment: вас понял, благодарю)

Answer (score 2):

пример Request Payload

```
var r ={n:22,k:5};
var s={
        r:r,
        b:1,
        a:25
    }
.......
xhr_send.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');
xhr_send.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
.......
xhr_send.send(JSON.stringify(s));
```